# How to make user chose their own embed color

Tags: python, discord, bots

so i have a discord bot and people can do r!say to well make the bot say things as a embed but its not working any help?

```
@client.command(aliases=['say'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def embed(ctx):

    questions = ["Which should be the tile of the embed?",
            "What should be the description?",
            "What is the color of the embed? This should be a hex color."]

    answers = []

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    for i in questions:
        await ctx.send(i)

        try:
            msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send('You did not answer in time. Please do it under 30 seconds next time.')
            return
        else:
            answers.append(msg.content)

    embedcolor = answers2[2]

    embed = discord.Embed(description=answers[1], title=answers[0], colour=int(embedcolor, 16))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

the error I get is
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'answers2' is not defined

Comment: Looks like there is a typo. I don't see answers2 defined anywhere in your code. Are you sure you did not want to write answers[2] instead of answers2[2] ?

Comment: thank you so much i did not see that @GuillaumeLabs

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mentioned, You probably meant to type answers[2] instead of answers2[2].

next time, copy and paste the entire error into a code block like this:

```
[
error here
error here
]
```